# Get full url from RouteUrl

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have problem with my application in production server because web site runs with url route "http://productionserver.com/myAppName/controllerName/actionName"

I need add to my JavaScript function full url.

Now I use in Razor and give it as input for some JavaScript function:

```
myFunc('@Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteUrlName")');
```

**JavaScript function:**

```
function MyFunc(nextUrl) {
    $('#btnName').on('click', function () {
        function CallBurooVaadeValjumineConfirmModal(callback) {
            //problem get this url
            $.get('/OtherController/CallConfirmModal', function (data) {
                var callConfirmModal = data.toLowerCase() === "true" ? true : false;
                callback(callConfirmModal);
            });
        }

        function Back() {

        }

        function Next() {
            $.get('/OtherController/Set'); 
            window.location.href = nextUrl;
        }

        //...other code
    });
}
```

In controller I have specified it:

```
[Route("myRouteController/myRouteAction", Name = "MyRouteUrlName")]
```

It returns "/myRouteController/myRouteAction", but I need for example "http://localhost:2000/myRouteController/myRouteAction" and where I go to production this url must be "http://productionserver.com/myAppName/myRouteController/myRouteAction"

How it possible do using `@Url.RouteUrl()`?

Comment: What makes you think you need the prefix? - `/myRouteController/myRouteAction` will go to the correct method

Comment: @StephenMuecke I write so that specify it: `[Route("myRouteController/myRouteAction", Name = "MyRouteUrlName")]`. Or I don't understand what prefix you mean. According your comment I edited my question that make it more clear.

Comment: You do not need the 'full' url (the `http://productionserver.com/myAppName` or `http://localhost:2000` is not necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem, problem was in Javascript side.

**Razor JavaScript func call**

```
MyFunc('@Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteUrlName")', '@Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteGetUrlName")', '@Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteSetUrlName")')
```

**Javascript**

```
function MyFunc(nextUrl, getUrl, setUrl) {
    $('#btnName').on('click', function () {
        function CallBurooVaadeValjumineConfirmModal(callback) {
            $.get(getUrl, function (data) {
                var callConfirmModal = data.toLowerCase() === "true" ? true : false;
                callback(callConfirmModal);
            });
        }

        function Back() {

        }

        function Next() {
            $.get(setUrl); 
            window.location.href = nextUrl;
        }

        //...other code
    });
}
```